# Java - Verticall scroll to JPanel with GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, grid-layout

In my Java app I have a `JPanel` with a `GridLayout` which displays a grid of 3 rows by 2 columns. It all works fine, but when I add a seventh element to the panel, the cells get resized.

What I want to achieve is that, during the seventh element insertion, the grid to remain 3 rows by 2 columns, all of the same size, and that the grid would be scrollable, but only vertically.

How can it be possible to achieve that?

Comment: 3 x 2 = 6, there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Have a look at [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

Comment: It's unclear what you really want to happen. You say that you want the grid to remain 3 rows by 2 columns. In that case, where do you want the seventh element to be? Do you mean that you want it to remain 2 columns but for a 4th row to be added with a scroll bar?

Answer (score 1):

It can't be 3 x 2 if you're adding a 7th element. Decide which should remain invariant: The number of columns or the number of rows? If columns, make the GridLayout `new GridLayout(0, 2)` for 2 columns and variable number of rows. If rows, then `new GridLayout(3, 0)` for 3 rows and a variable number of columns.

Comment: The answer is probably the merge of both answers. If he wants to keep the grid in a 3x2 frame, he just need to wrap the grid your answer defines in a scrollable pane

Comment: What I want to achieve is to set fixed columns to 2, and that element (cell) height would be preserved, and if there is no more space, show next element on scroll. What I'm getting though are the cell height being reduced to fit without scrollbars. And wrapping the JPanel in a JScrollPane doesn't fix, because the column width isn't half of screen width.

Comment: @ErnestinaJuan: Please edit your question and show an image of what you're desiring to create. Also, if you can create and post a [mcve], it would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your panel to a JScrollPane. You can specify which scroll bars to display.